# Material UI TexField Input Time Picker does not change value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

Used this: https://codesandbox.io/s/5154qzmjl as an example of the material UI time picker and now in trouble, because I can't change value of the time.

I am mapping the days array in the state to the TextField:

```
this.state = {
    days: [
                { day: 0, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
                { day: 1, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
                { day: 2, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
                { day: 3, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
                { day: 4, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
                { day: 5, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
                { day: 6, fromHour: 9, fromMin: 0, toHour: 17, toMin: 30 },
            ],
}


render() {
        const {
            days,
        } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
            {
                    days.map((e, index) => (
                        <Card
                            key={e.day}
                            className={classes.card}>
                            <CardContent>
                                <TextField
                                    id="time"
                                    label="From Time"
                                    type="time"
                                    value={e.fromHour.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + e.fromMin.toString().padStart(2, '0')}
                                    inputProps={{
                                        step: 300, // 5 min
                                    }}
                                />
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                    ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

NOte the handle time function, have to convert to a string in order to render. However the values are stuck to the ones I defined in my state. How do I change them? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

According to Material-ui documenation, the value property of textfied accepts the following:

```
union: string |
 number |
 bool |
 arrayOf
```

So your function does not evaluate

Comment: thank you. I just checked the return of the function handleTime using typeof and it returned 'string', which is one of the Material-UI value properties.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain that right. It doesn't matter what your function evaluates to (which is a string in your case) but what value you pass. Which can be the ones I mentioned above. Look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/m72z99jzp. I have passed the disabled property which only accepts a bool. But instead I followed your approach and passed a function that returns true. As you can see, true doesn't evaluate and the textfield remains disabled. So you can only pass the values above and functions are not accepted

Comment: sorry, but if it remains disabled, doesn't it mean that it does evaluate? What should I make my state be then?

Comment: I have excluded the function for clarity and am rendering the time directly inside of the value property. Should work now, right? Unfortunately, not

Comment: I might be wrong here then. How about this part of your code:

`renderAvailabilities() {
        const {
            days,
        } = this.state;`
is that a mistake? I don't see a clear render function...

Comment: no worries, this i just one of my render components. I changed it to render to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on controlled components: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

The value of the textfield is controlled by the state variable you used. When your try to change the value of the input, it does not update because your state variables are not updated. You need to add a change event handler to the text field and update the state value when the input is changed.
Relevant code from the link:

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

In your case you would have to parse the value into hours and minutes to set them separately. You also need to pass the day number so you can update the correct element within the array. You might want to rethink your state structure, and object with the day number as the key might be easier to update than the array you have now.

Answer (score 0):

Burhan B is right. In your TextField component add an onChange prop. Set the value to this.state.value or value since you are already destructuring you state.

Pseudo Code

```
state = {
  days: [...], //your objects go here just omitted for the sake of space
  time: moment().format("insert your format") }
  ...
handleChange = time => {
  this.setState({ time }) 
}
render(){
  const { days, time } = this.state; 
  return (
   <div> ...
    <TextField
     id="time"
     label="From Time"
     type="time"
     value={time}
     onChange = {this.handleChange}
     inputProps={{
       step: 300, // 5 min
     }}
   />
```

moment().format comes from MomentJS. MomentJS is package that handles dates and times. Alternatively you can use Date-fns. I suggest using this because it looks like you are manually trying to format the date in your value prop and I'm not sure that is the best approach. These packages come with formatting and return an ISODate. The formatting is for the front end and the ISODate is useful for your backend (assuming you are sending this to a db).

Certainly you do not have to use either one of those packages. If you don't perhaps have another component that formats the time for you or a function that formats the time. This makes the code a lot more readable and a lot easier to update.

Hope that helps.